# Dataframe size keep growing although its count is not growing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need some help
I have problems with apache-spark when i use for loop to update dataframe. its size keeps growing unlimited although its count is not growing

Can u suggest me how to fix it or guide me why my dataframe size is keep growing all the time? (T^T)//
my program run on local[6] using spark2.0.1

@this is my code

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val df1 = initial dataframe(read from db)
    while(){
        val word_count_df = processAndCountText() // query data from database and do word count
        val temp_df1 = update(df1,word_count_df )
        temp_df1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        df1.unpersist()
        df1 = temp_df1

        println(temp_df1.count())
        println(s"${SizeEstimator.estimate(temp_df1) / 1073741824.0} GB")
    }
}
```

//Edited
This is update function that updates some row that has key in word_count_df.
I tried to split it to 2 dataframes and compute it separately then return the union of 2 dataframes but it takes too much time because it need to enable "spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled"

```
def update(u_stateful_df : DataFrame, word_count_df : DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    val run_time = current_end_time_m - start_time_ms / 60000
    val calPenalty = udf { (last_update_duration: Long, run_time: Long) => calculatePenalty(last_update_duration, run_time) }
    //calculatePenalty is simple math function using for loop and return double
    val calVold = udf { (v_old: Double, penalty_power: Double) => v_old * Math.exp(penalty_power) }


    //(word_new,count_new)
    val word_count_temp_df = word_count_df
            .withColumnRenamed("word", "word_new")
            .withColumnRenamed("count", "count_new")

    //u_stateful_df  (word,u,v,a,last_update,count)
    val state_df = u_stateful_df
            .join(word_count_temp_df, u_stateful_df("word") === word_count_temp_df("word_new"), "outer")
            .na.fill(Map("last_update" -> start_time_ms / 60000))
            .na.fill(0.0)
            .withColumn("word", when(col("word").isNotNull, col("word")).otherwise(col("word_new")))
            .withColumn("count", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, col("count_new")).otherwise(-1))
            .drop("count_new")
            .withColumn("current_end_time_m", lit(current_end_time_m))
            .withColumn("last_update_duration", col("current_end_time_m") - col("last_update"))
            .filter(col("last_update_duration") < ResourceUtility.one_hour_duration_ms / 60000)
            .withColumn("run_time", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, lit(run_time)))
            .withColumn("penalty_power", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, calPenalty(col("last_update_duration"), col("run_time"))))
            .withColumn("v_old_penalty", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, calVold(col("v"), col("penalty_power"))))
            .withColumn("v_new", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, col("count") / run_time))
            .withColumn("v_sum", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, col("v_old_penalty") + col("v_new")))
            .withColumn("a", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, (col("v_sum") - col("v")) / col("last_update_duration")).otherwise(col("a")))
            .withColumn("last_update", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, lit(current_end_time_m)).otherwise(col("last_update")))
            .withColumn("u", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, col("v")).otherwise(col("u")))
            .withColumn("v", when(col("word_new").isNotNull, col("v_sum")).otherwise(col("v")))

    state_df.select("word", "u", "v", "a", "last_update", "count")
}
```

@this is my log

```
u_stateful_df : 1408665
size of dataframe size : 0.8601360470056534 GB

u_stateful_df : 1408665
size of dataframe size : 1.3347024470567703 GB

u_stateful_df : 268498
size of dataframe size : 1.5012029185891151 GB

u_stateful_df : 147232
size of dataframe size : 3.287795402109623 GB

u_stateful_df : 111950
size of dataframe size : 4.761911824345589 GB

....
....

u_stateful_df : 72067
size of dataframe size : 14.510709017515182 GB
```

@This is log when i write it to file

```
I save df1 as CSV in the file system. below is the size of dataframe in file system, count and size(track by org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator).     



csv size 84.2 MB     
u_stateful_df : 1408665     
size of dataframe size : 0.4460855945944786 GB     



csv size 15.2 MB     
u_stateful_df : 183315     
size of dataframe size : 0.522 GB     



csv size 9.96 MB     
u_stateful_df : 123381     
size of dataframe size : 0.630GB     



csv size 4.63 MB     
u_stateful_df : 56896     
size of dataframe size : 0.999 GB

...
...
...

csv size 3.47 MB
u_stateful_df : 43104
size of dataframe size : 3.1956922858953476 GB
```

Comment: I suppose the solution is inside `update` function, can you post it's code?

Comment: to  Mariusz, thx for your attention. I add the update function to post that u request ><.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find the bug inside `update`, I was expecting to find something that makes rows bigger or some memory leak... Please try another one experiment - instead of using `SizeEstimator` simply write this data to filesystem in row format (csv/json) and check if it's size is growing.

Comment: I also track the computer memory, its memory consumption is same as size of dataframe.

Comment: to Mariusz, i paste the log that show the size of CSV in file system in the post :)

Comment: I save df1 as CSV in the file system. below is the size of dataframe in file system, count and size(track by org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator).     
     
     
     
csv size 84.2 MB     
u_stateful_df : 1408665     
size of dataframe size : 0.4460855945944786 GB     
     
     
     
csv size 15.2 MB     
u_stateful_df : 183315     
size of dataframe size : 0.522 GB     
     
     
     
csv size 9.96 MB     
u_stateful_df : 123381     
size of dataframe size : 0.630GB     


  
csv size 4.63 MB     
u_stateful_df : 56896     
size of dataframe size : 0.999 GB

Comment: I have added answer based on your logs :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some leak inside Spark. Usually when you call `persist` or `cache` on Dataframe and then `count` Spark generates results and stores it inside distributed memory or on disks, but also knows whole execution plan to rebuild that Dataframe in case of lost executor or something. But it should not take so much space...

As far as i know there is no option to "collapse" Dataframe (to tell Spark to forget whole execution plan) other that simply writing to storage and then read from this storage.

Comment: thank you sir. (^0^)//    
Is there any solution to fix it?    
I need to run this algorithm in while loop using spark to verify the result of sparkstreaming (i also code spark streaming and it shares the same API)

Comment: Write data to temporary directory and read them in loop (instead of persisting in cache), I suppose it's the only way...